# Is memory uniformly distributed in a computer or an a disk?

Tags: caching, memory, stack, dynamic-memory-allocation, ram

In CS, there are different memory types, such as the Stack and the Heap. However, on a physical level, are they the same, and these concepts are just for the software writers? Or are there different types of memory in a given computer. I know that there are differences in a HDD and SSD storage, but what about a given disc? On a given HDD, would every block of memory be the same as others?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the title question is, "Not necessarily." Software determines how memory is allocated. It's possible that the software will use memory starting at physical address and moving up, or in reverse order, or randomly, etc. So if you're using 50% of the total memory, it could be scattered all over the place, or it could be the bottom half of physical memory.

Same is true of a disk. It's up to the software (probably the driver software, but possibly the disk controller) where things are placed physically on the disk.

There are, of course, reserved areas, but again those are by convention. For example, boot loaders are placed in fixed areas on disk drives, BIOS entry points are placed at specific memory addresses, etc.

In general, a memory location is a memory location. Your program asks for a block of memory of a certain size, the operating system's memory allocator will return you a pointer to memory. You might be using that block of physical memory for a program's heap, whereas in the past the same block might have been used for the executable code of some other program.

Memory is memory. With the exception of a few reserved areas used by the operating system or the machine BIOS, it's all the same. The same goes for disk space.